# Compiling C library for android

Tags: android, c, android-studio, android-ndk

As a proof of concept, I’m trying to compile and utilize the power of [this](https://github.com/tpruvot/cpuminer-multi) library for an android app. I'm using the android studio. What I've done so far was:

1. Installed NDK and SDK (I would like to target android version 4.0.3 and above if possible)
2. Created an android project in Android Studio
3. Created the JNI folder in
4. Stored all the contents of the library in my JNI folder
5. Linked my build.gradle to the Android.MK file that was present in the sources

   ```
   externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path 'src/main/jni/Android.mk'
        }
   }
   ```
6. Set ProductFlavors in order to avoid trying to make a build for architectures that are not supported by the library (i might be wrong here already)

   ```
   productFlavors {
       dev { ndk.abiFilters 'x86', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a' }
       develx86 { ndk.abiFilters 'x86', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a' }
       production { ndk.abiFilters 'x86', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a' }
       productionx86 { ndk.abiFilters 'x86', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a' }
   }
   ```
7. At this point, I've noticed that some files like cpu-miner.c are missing some includes highlighting them as missing, specifically

   ```
   #include <curl/curl.h>
   #include <openssl/sha.h>`
   ```

So I went to the official websites of these two libraries and downloaded the sources, created two corresponding folders and places all the files there. In `OpenSSL` there was an h.in file - a config as I understand. I was able to get a configured one from [here](https://github.com/luvit/openssl/blob/master/openssl-configs/arm/openssl/opensslconf.h) (might also be a place where I made a mistake)

8. I've added Application.mk to JNI folder root with the following content `APP_ABI:= armeabi armeabi-v7a x86` to exclude some of the architectures I don't support.

At this point, I have some problems - one of them is that I can't actually build my JNI stuff with NDK-build - `sched.h` doesn't get resolved (even if I increase API version to 20). This results in errors like:

```
JNI/cpu-miner.c:473:2: error: use of undeclared identifier 'cpu_set_t'
    cpu_set_t set;
jni/cpu-miner.c:474:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'set'
    CPU_ZERO(&set);
```

So the questions are:

1. How can I force the build to resolve `sched.h`?
2. Was my approach correct with downloading and adding the sources of missing libraries or there was some other option - I assume that there is one indeed because they were not included in the library source code? If so - could somebody please provide instructions how to do this with NDK (or it doesn't matter what I use for that?)
3. As soon as I fix the library build will it be enough to just generate java interface to my c files and start using them or there are additional steps to consider?

   Please feel free to ask for any additional details if you require any, thank you in advance.
   Disclaimer: I'm the a.NET dev so please be more specific about android/C things where applicable.
   Disclaimer 2: This program is being made for educational purposes as a proof of concept.

Comment: The include looks like working. The problem that it types are not defined. if you take a look at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/73a5a3b/ndk/platforms/android-20/include/sched.h - there is interesting macro guard `_GNU_SOURCE`

Comment: I actually have this `#define _GNU_SOURCE` at the start of cpu-miner.c

Comment: just saying that the problem could be somehow related to the meaning of `_GNU_SOURCE` macro within NDK context.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't look so as I don't know of an alternative way to make ndk see this macro and it is already defined at the start of file

Comment: **1)** Let us separate the issues of **ndk-build** and Android Studio integration. Start with the former, and run **ndk-build -B V=1 APP_ABI=armeabi** on command line (use **jni** as you current directory).

Comment: **2)** yes, these libraries are explicitly mentioned as external dependencies in [README](https://github.com/tpruvot/cpuminer-multi/blob/linux/README.md)

Comment: **3)** Note that the GitHub project builds an executable, not a library

Comment: @AlexCohn I've tried using these flags, the problem is is stil lget an error `error: use of undeclared identifier 'cpu_set_t'`I've tried sdk version 15, sd version 21 and even including the sources of [from here](https://github.com/android/platform_bionic/blob/master/libc/include/sched.h) - still getting errors related to sched.h

Comment: The point of using "V=1" is to get verbose output in your build log. If you cannot figure out what went wrong by reading this log, try posting it here.

Comment: My error if i run nds-build with the specified parameters and my project path is: `.../jni/cpu-miner.c:473:2: error:
      use of undeclared identifier 'cpu_set_t'
        cpu_set_t set;` - the same, it can't find sched even while it is included in the project.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `cpu_set_t` didn't make it into the NDK headers until android-21.

NDK r14 (unreleased, but should be out next week) has completely redone the headers so that you'll have access to the struct definitions and constants (whether or not the APIs you'll need will be available before android-21 is a different question). To use them, grab the [r14 beta](https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/wiki#downloads) and follow the instructions for [unified headers](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/UnifiedHeaders.md).

Comment: Raising api version to 21 made the code not red but the error dustring the build is still there and the include itself is greyed out. I've checked and it point to versions 21 now

Comment: My guess would be that it only failed for some of the ABIs. Try @AlexCohn's suggestion of running `ndk-build` directly. If that works, try expanding `APP_ABI` to include armeabi-v7a and x86 until you find one that fails. The output of any of these failing commands would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try add this before your include `<sched.h>`

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
```

In case if it doesn't work, just add below structure in you `cpu-miner.c` file:

```
#define CPU_SETSIZE 1024
#define __NCPUBITS  (8 * sizeof (unsigned long))
typedef struct
{
   unsigned long __bits[CPU_SETSIZE / __NCPUBITS];
} cpu_set_t;
```

Comment: Thank you. This has helped me to get going further, but now i have tonns of errors like `jni/cpu-miner.c:1487: error: undefined reference to 'json_object_get'`  ,  `jni/compat/jansson/jansson.h:109: error: undefined reference to 'json_delete'`  ,  `jni/cpu-miner.c:2900: error: undefined reference to 'json_load_file'`  and so on.

Comment: Do you have json library included?
Try adding LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -ljson in your Android.mk

Comment: Thanks again for your input. Adding this line started to cause error `error: cannot find -ljson`. P.S. even without this line i can navigate to the specified type from the code, it is stored in `jansson.h`, so i guess the problem could be somewhere else